# AS3 and XML Filtering by time

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, xml-parsing, flash-cs6

I have some XML that i am pulling into flash with AS3.

This is the XML that is loaded into the flash :

```
               <Flights>
  <flight>
    <number>GS1234</number>
    <date>10/11/2015</date>
    <time>1440</time>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <number>TD1234</number>
    <date>10/11/2015</date>
    <time>1450</time>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <number>DDS342</number>
    <date>11/11/2015</date>
    <time>1540</time>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <number>EJ8888</number>
    <date>11/11/2015</date>
    <time>1550</time>
  </flight>
  <flight>
    <number>DEV666</number>
    <date>12/11/2015</date>
    <time>1600</time>
  </flight>
</Flights>
```

What i need to do is filter this but by time, an hour ahead of a given time.

So if i enter the time 14:20, it will return all the flights that are within the time range of 14:20 and 15:20.

Is this possible any easier than putting everything into an array and looping through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to convert to an array. You can use [e4x filtering](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html), and since your times are formatted as a number its a simple numeric comparison:

```
var departing:XMLList = xml.flight.(time > 1420 && time < 1520);
```

Gives you:

```
<flight>
  <number>GS1234</number>
  <date>10/11/2015</date>
  <time>1440</time>     </flight>
 <flight>
  <number>TD1234</number>
  <date>10/11/2015</date>
  <time>1450</time>
</flight>
```